# Unity - How should i give orders to my Harvester AI using a Behaviour Tree?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a personal small RTS project in Unity, and I'm trying to build my Unit AI, for Harvester, Solider etc..
I build a Behaviour Tree with a few different Node, everything is working well on this side,
My problem is how can I give orders to my Units
For now, I have a harvester AI in my scene, it harvests resources around and transport them to the warehouse
The units selection is working, and if I right click  somewhere on the terrain the order is send to the selected units
My problem start here, I don't know if I'm doing it the right way
I assign the `targetPosition` to my unit, and turn a `_hasOrder` boolean to true
In my **BehavioutTree**, the first sequence is about orders, it check if `_hasOrder` is true and then do the stuff
The problem is, this sequence is never running..
If someone has an idea, maybe I should pause the behavior tree when I give any kind of order to my AI and resume the Tree when the order is done ?

The thing that make me think I'm not doing it the right way, is when I try to imagine how could I stop the current order if I give a new one, example, I give the order to go to a location multiple times, the only one which should be take into account is the last, so previous order has to be ignored

```cs
public class HarvestingUnit : BaseUnit
{
        [SerializeField] private HarvestingBuilding _associatedBuilding = default;
        private int _inventorySlots = 1;
        private int _collectedResources = 0;
        private float _harvestingTime = 3.0f;



        protected override Node SetupTree()
        {
            Node root = new Selector(new List<Node>
            {
                // First sequence will execute only when _hasOrder is true
                new Sequence(new List<Node>
                {
                    new Condition(() => _hasOrder == true),
                    new GiveTarget(() => _targetPosition),
                    new TaskGoTo(transform, _agent),
                    new ActionNode(() => _hasOrder = false),
                }),


                // Second sequence
                new Sequence(new List<Node>
                {                       
                    new CheckForAvailableResource(_associatedBuilding),

                    // A selector with two child nodes to handle harvesting and transporting resources
                    new Selector(new List<Node>
                    {
                        // Transport collected resources to warehouse if inventory is full
                        new Sequence(new List<Node>
                        {
                            new Condition(() => _collectedResources == _inventorySlots),
                            new GiveTarget(() => _associatedBuilding.GetNearestWarehoursePosition()),
                            new TaskTransportResource(transform, _agent, _associatedBuilding.GetNearestWarehoursePosition()),
                            new ActionNode(() => _collectedResources = 0)
                        }),

                        // Harvest resources while collected resources are less than inventory slots
                        new Sequence(new List<Node>
                        {
                            new Repeater(new List<Node>
                            {                    
                                new Condition(() => _collectedResources < _inventorySlots),
                                new TaskGoTo(transform, _agent),
                                new TaskHarvest(transform),
                                new Wait(_harvestingTime),
                                new ActionNode(() => _collectedResources++),
                            })
                        }),
                    })
                })
            });
            // Reset the tree when the behaviour is restarted
            root.Reset();
            return root;
        }
    }

    public void Move(Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        _hasOrder = true;
        Debug.Log(_hasOrder);
        _targetPosition = targetPosition;
    }
}
```

```cs
public abstract class Tree : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Node _root = null;

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        _root = SetupTree();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(_root != null)
        {
            _root.Evaluate();
        }
    }

    protected abstract Node SetupTree();
}
```

I already tried adding multiples Condition node to check `_hasOrder` value but nothing has worked as intended..

I hope I gave enough information to understand my problem..

Comment: Here we can't see who is calling `SetupTree()` and what is happening with the `Node` that is returned. Try stepping with debugger from the entry point where your move command issued and sent to Harvester, and if no success, post more code that is executed before and after the given method.

Comment: What I also can see here, is a lack of abstraction. In the RTS games your units are pretty much the same and should be able to follow narrow set of commands, i.e. Move to Position, Follow, Stop and maybe couple more. More complex commands could be built out of these bricks, so you don't need to do things like `_harvester.GoHarvest()`, but instead `_unit.SendOrder(new MoveTo(selectedTarget).Then(new UseAbility(_unit.MainAbility));`

Comment: I edited my post to add the Tree code, so you can see where SetupTree is called and for what the returned Node is used for.
I was thinking a BehaviourTree will fit my needs :/

Comment: No, the structure is OK here, you just miss the names and the control over tree creation process (pretty much everything is hardocred). If you make each small behavior, a unique  type of action, like a blocks in Minecraft, you could carefully assemble complex behaviors in Editor visually and even swap them at runtime. Blocks like `MoveToPosition`, `FollowTarget`, `Attack`, `Retreat` etc. could be stored in ScriptableObjects, and another ScriptableObject could store assembled trees for different types of units (ground unit, flying unit, worker, invisible...).

Comment: I had looked at your code again, here's my thoughts: 1. You're using simple node as a base class to build a tree, while also extending node so they could store other nodes and iterate over them with some pattern (`Sequence`, `Repeater`...). Did you looked at those classes, did you stepped them through debugger to figure out if they are working correctly? 2. I also don't see a code of `Selector` class, tho it might be pretty important in the context of what's happening. 3. Do unit tests on your classes, both with normal and corner cases - it helps a lot, beleive me.